# clip-path css men image not show up on div

Tags: html, css

Please help me to solve this issue, image not working z-index when div on clip-path. how i z-index to image easily thanks

Please check my code :-

```css
.mymap {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 80%, 0 23%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 80%, 0 23%);
}

.mymap {
  height: 220px;
}

.men img {
  width: 20%;
}

.men img {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="mymap">
  <div class="men">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1c/01/27/1c0127d19cdd75efb5a3eca4384658d5.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen link :- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaQoOX

Please check and tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the `background-image` isn't loading, which might be confusing. The hosting server seems to be denying the request. Try another image.

Comment: Hello @PerSalbark Thanks for your great reply. please check the codepen link please thanks Here is the codepen link :- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaQoOX

Comment: edit question please check

Answer (score 1):

You need to to wrap .mymap and .men class into parent container and set `position:relative` to .container class and `position:absolute` to image.

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.mymap {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 80%, 0 23%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 80%, 0 23%);
}

.mymap {
  height: 220px;
}

.men img {
  width: 20%;
}

.men img {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mymap"></div>
  <div class="men">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1c/01/27/1c0127d19cdd75efb5a3eca4384658d5.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can optimize by making the `mymap` a pseudo element